# Is using pm2 with node.js in cluster mode safe

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, mongodb, pm2

So pm2 is a process manager that allows me to start multiple instances of my app on the same server. How it works is that it load balances the requests to all instances.
So I thought that this is some form of fake multi-threading to Node.js environments. Then I thought of the following scenario:

> What if my Node.js app instances are connected to MongoDB and instance
>   0 is doing a find request while at the same time instance 1 is
>   actually inserting into the same collection?

MongoDB is NOT single threaded and it has a thread pool. Does that mean that there is a possible clash or is thread safety now related to some form of mutex in MongoDB?
This is just an example case. Is there a possibility for pm2 to cause problems like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use PM2 in all of my node applications. As far as cluster mode goes it is as safe as it can be (at least in my experience). There are some caveats to be aware of in PM2 though.

1. Pay attention to your configuration file. No matter what format you will use (JSON YAML etc) you need to understand the ramifications of each setting. For instance using max cores etc.
2. I would advise strongly not to use the watch parameter. It seems to slow up the system and I have had trouble with memory allocation on it.
3. Use PM2 Monit to monitor just what is going on on the server so you can be on top of things.
4. If you are dealing with a robust production which requires sophisticated clustering then it would be advisable to take a look at other though costly options. In a large, diversified and heavily used cluster system I would not put the entire cluster operation in the hands of one system.

But safe? As far as my experience, yes.

Answer (score 1):

From [MongoDB's docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), it has support for Concurrency Control.

> Concurrency control allows multiple applications to run concurrently without causing data inconsistency or conflicts

If you need to update multiple documents, you can use its $isolated operator

> Using the $isolated operator, a write operation that affects multiple documents can prevent other processes from interleaving once the write operation modifies the first document. This ensures that no client sees the changes until the write operation completes or errors out.

Note that $isolated does not work with sharded clusters, but I'm assuming you're working with just one MongoDB database instance.

Comment: Thanks kane. That basically answers most of my question. But do you have an idea if pm2 can cause problems in general?

Comment: I haven't used pm2 so I don't know if it has specific issues. In general, make sure your load balancer doesn't hand off the same user/session's requests to different nodejs instances if the nodejs hold any transient state. If all nodejs requests are stateless, (everything is persisted to DB), then I don't imagine any issues